how to use 'loop-playlist' option with a profile?
I would like to create a profile that applies to .png files, so that when a animated png file is playing, I would like for it to be looped, I tried:
#____________________ GIF _____________________
 [extension.gif]
 geometry=40%
 speed=1.0
#____________________ apng|png _____________________
 [extension.png]
 geometry=40%
 speed=1.0
 loop-playlist=inf
 #--loop-playlist=inf    #I tried this line too,

The above though, does not work. when I place  --loop-playlist=inf above all profiles it works, but then all videos, regardless of its extension, are looped.
How do I make this work??
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
